# Eclipse console does not show the end result

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class PrimeFinder implements Runnable {
    Thread go;
    StringBuffer primes = new StringBuffer();
    int time = 0;

    public PrimeFinder() {
        start();
        while (primes != null) {
            System.out.println(time);
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(InterruptedException exc) {
                // do nothing
            }
            time++;
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        if (go == null) {
            go = new Thread(this);
            go.start();
        }
    }

    public void run() {
        int quantity = 1_000_000;
        int numPrimes = 0;
        // candidate: the number that might be prime
        int candidate = 2;
        primes.append("\nFirst ").append(quantity).append(" primes:\n\n");
        while (numPrimes < quantity) {
            if (isPrime(candidate)) {
                primes.append(candidate).append(" ");
                numPrimes++;
            }
            candidate++;
        }
        System.out.println(primes);
        primes = null;
        System.out.println("\nTime elapsed: " + time + " seconds");
    }

    public static boolean isPrime(int checkNumber) {
        double root = Math.sqrt(checkNumber);
        for (int i = 2; i <= root; i++) {
            if (checkNumber % i == 0) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] arguments) {
        new PrimeFinder();
    }
}
```

As the title states I do not get the end result of the program in the console... The timer does count, until the calculation is done, but when the program is supposed to print out the result, the console clears and goes all blank. I tried to enter my code in some kind of online compiler, and sure enough, I got the end result printed out. Has anyone had similar problem and if so, how did you manage to fix it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The problem is that the line with the prime numbers gets too long (8.245.905 characters). `primes.append(candidate).append('\n');` works for me.

Comment: Oh shoot, this did actualy work, or kind of. It prints out only the last part of the StringBuffer, but still, it's far better than nothing. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this in IntelliJ and the output is retained in the console - though it's not all retained when using Eclipse as you point out. Looks like Eclipse maybe overwrites the console upon switching threads.

You could just write the output to a file and view it there, although this is of course different from retaining it in the console. To do that you would go to *Run* > *Run Configurations...*, then select your application under *Java Application*, then click the *Common* tab, then under *Standard Input and Output* check the *Output file* checkbox and enter a log file path and file name for where you want logs to go, then *Apply*. Then run that "Run Configuration" and view the output in the file.

If running on a server (e.g., tomcat) from within Eclipse, you would go to the Server view, double-click your server, click *Open launch configuration*, then *Common*, then *Output file*. From there you can specify an output destination on your file system or in your Eclipse workspace.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not running on a server. I checked my Run Configurations and everything seems to be fine- Allocate Console is checked.

Comment: I haven't tried your code in my Eclipse - but it works great for me in IntelliJ.

Comment: Just tried it in Eclipse and it does the same - the console data disappears. Ha, strange.

Comment: Actually, it disappears at first, then after some seconds this shows: "18 Time elapsed: 19 seconds".

Comment: Yep, same with me, I forgot to mention that above. It actually acts kind of strange with all multithreaded programs, now that i think about it ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Hm, well you can write the output to a file and see it all there - just can't seem to retain it in the console.

Answer (score 0):

If you started the Thread instead of just doing the instantiation, maybe it would print something out.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new PrimeFinder());
thread.start();
```